# Update existing ticket in VTiger

Tags: php, crm, issue-tracking, ticket-system, vtiger

I am a newbie to VTiger, I am using the 5.2.0 version to try, learn implementing Issue Tracking.

**Intro:**

A client sends an email to say support@company.com, Mail Converter or Mail Scanner.. scans for the new email and if found creates a new ticket.

If admin sees a new ticket which is being raised in Trouble Tickets, makes some changes such as assigning it to someone, or making a comment etc.. VTiger CRM sends an email to a client saying that admin has made modifications to the ticket.

Lets say Client wants some changes, so he replies to support@company.com, a new ticket is raised because a new mail as arrived and mail scanner creates a new ticket.

**Problem:**

Instead of updating an existing ticket which the client has sent before, creating a new ticket everytime duplicates the problem by making many tickets for one issue, which is a big problem.

When ever a client sends a mail to support@company.com, Subject of email goes as Title of the Ticket and Body of Email as Description of Ticket.

Lets say

```
Title of Ticket is SubjectClientSent
```

Client didnot like something after admin makes some modifications and the client decides to reply to the email which VTiger has sent him, it is generally in this manner.

```
Re: TT17 [ Ticket Id : 22 ] Re : SubjectClientSent
```

I dont want Mail Scanner to create a new ticket with the title of ticket as `Re: TT17 [ Ticket Id : 22 ] Re : SubjectClientSent` , I want it to update the exiting ticket with title `SubjectClientSent`

I tried to do that with creating a new rule something like this..

[image]

But, its still creating a new ticket.

Could you help me correct this?

Is there a better way of updating the existing ticket?

Thanks for the help and support.

Comment: Sorry for irrelevant comment but I want you to please help me in my Vtiger issue. Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13178041/how-to-extend-vtiger-crm-products

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Found the solution!**

**The entire answer was written stealing information from the [VTiger PDF document](http://forge.vtiger.com/frs/download.php/846/vtigercrm-510-mailscanner-autoticketing.pdf), [VTiger Forum](http://forums.vtiger.com/viewtopic.php?t=25405&postdays=0&postorder=asc&highlight=set+rule&start=30), [VTiger Bug Link](http://trac.vtiger.com/cgi-bin/trac.cgi/ticket/6391)**

The below pictures shows the **basic process involved in automating ticketing with MailScanner or MailConverter**

![Mail Scanner Basic Process][4]

**1:**
Customer (having a Contact/Account record) sends email to support@company.com, with subject
“Test Trouble Ticket”

**2:**
Mail Scanner creates ticket, links it to matching contact/account record filtered by emailid
lookup.
HelpDeskHandler will send a acknowledgment email with more information on how to respond
further to Customer. The email subject looks like “TT15 [Ticket Id: 1483] Test Trouble Ticket”

**3:**
Customer replies to the acknowledgment email keeping part of the subject intact to
support@company.com. As mail scanner is configured with Regex rule on subject and finds a
matching Trouble Ticket linked to Customer, it updates the comments with the email body.

**4:**
When support team update their comment, an email is sent to Customer again.

The following steps will help us achieve this functionality

**Step 1: Setup Outgoing Mail Server**

If your Outgoing Mail Server is Gmail, the following settings should work for you

```
Mail Server Settings (SMTP)     
Server Name ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 
User Name   username@gmail.com 
Password    ******  
From Email  from.email@gmail.com 
Requires Authentication?    Yes
```

**Step 2: Setup MailScanner or MailConverter**

```
DEFAULT Information 

Scanner Name    DEFAULT
Server Name     imap.gmail.com
Protocol       imap4
User Name     support.company@gmail.com
SSL Type       ssl
SSL Method      novalidate-cert
Connect URL     {imap.gmail.com:993/imap4/ssl/novalidate-cert}
Status       Enabled

Scanning Information 

Look for    All Messages from lastscan
After scan   Mark message as Read
```

**Step 3: Setup Rules to create & update tickets in MailScanner or MailConverter**

```
Rules For Mail Converter [DEFAULT] 

    Priority    
    From    
    To  
    Subject     Regex   Ticket Id[^:]?: ([0-9]+)
    Body        
    Match   All Condition
    Action  Update Ticket

    Priority    
    From    
    To  
    Subject         
    Body        
    Match   Any Condition
    Action  Create Ticket
```

**Step 4: Configure config.inc.php**

*update the following variables in your config.inc.php*

**$HELPDESK_SUPPORT_EMAIL_ID**

*FROM address information to be used when sending mails
Example: automated-reply@company.com*

```
$HELPDESK_SUPPORT_EMAIL_ID = 'auto.reply.company@gmail.com';
```

**$HELPDESK_SUPPORT_NAME**

*FROM name to be used for purpose of display for emails sentout.
Example: Automated Reply*

```
$HELPDESK_SUPPORT_NAME = 'Company Support';
```

**$HELPDESK_SUPPORT_EMAIL_REPLY_ID**

*REPLY-TO address to be set in the email sent.
Example: support@company.com*

```
$HELPDESK_SUPPORT_EMAIL_REPLY_ID = 'support.company@gmail.com';
```

*Setting this information is one of the important step for autoticketing.
When user tries to Reply for the automated emails the TO
address will be set by the mail-client and reaches the MailBox for
which we have setup the scanning.*

**Step 5: Create HelpDeskHandler.php** *in VTigerCRM/modules/HelpDesk/*

```
<?php
/*+**********************************************************************************
 * The contents of this file are subject to the vtiger CRM Public License Version 1.0
 * ("License"); You may not use this file except in compliance with the License
 * The Original Code is:  vtiger CRM Open Source
 * The Initial Developer of the Original Code is vtiger.
 * Portions created by vtiger are Copyright (C) vtiger.
 * All Rights Reserved.
 ************************************************************************************/

class HelpDeskHandler extends VTEventHandler {

  function __getSendToEmail($crmid) {
    if(empty($crmid)) return false;

    $sendtoemail = false;

    global $adb;

    $metaresult = $adb->pquery("SELECT setype FROM vtiger_crmentity WHERE crmid=? AND deleted = 0", array($crmid));
    if($metaresult && $adb->num_rows($metaresult)) {
      $metaresultrow = $adb->fetch_array($metaresult);

      $emailres = false;

      if($metaresultrow['setype'] == 'Contacts') {
        $emailres = $adb->pquery("SELECT email,yahooid FROM vtiger_contactdetails WHERE contactid = ?", array($crmid));
      } else if($metaresultrow['setype'] == 'Accounts') {
        $emailres = $adb->pquery("SELECT email1,email2 FROM vtiger_account WHERE accountid = ?", array($crmid));
      }

      if($emailres && $adb->num_rows($emailres)) {
        $emailresrow = $adb->fetch_array($emailres);

        if(!empty($emailresrow[0])) $sendtoemail = $emailresrow[0];
        if(!empty($emailresrow[1])) $sendtoemail = $emailresrow[1];

      }

    }
    return $sendtoemail;

  }


  function handleEvent($eventName, $entityData) {
    global $log, $adb;

    if($eventName == 'vtiger.entity.aftersave') {
      $moduleName = $entityData->getModuleName();

      // Event not related to HelpDesk - IGNORE
      if($moduleName != 'HelpDesk') {
        return;
      }

      // Take action if the service running is MailScanner (either via Cron/Scan Now)
      if(isset($_REQUEST) && $_REQUEST['service'] == 'MailScanner' ) {

        $focus = $entityData->focus;

        $sendToEmail = $this->__getSendToEmail($focus->column_fields['parent_id']); 

        // If the entity is create new and we know whom to send the mail proceed.
        if($entityData->isNew() && $sendToEmail) {
          global $HELPDESK_SUPPORT_EMAIL_ID, $HELPDESK_SUPPORT_NAME, $HELPDESK_SUPPORT_EMAIL_REPLY_ID;

          include_once 'vtlib/Vtiger/Mailer.php';
          $mailer = new Vtiger_Mailer();
          $mailer->ConfigSenderInfo($HELPDESK_SUPPORT_EMAIL_ID, $HELPDESK_SUPPORT_NAME);
          $mailer->AddReplyTo($HELPDESK_SUPPORT_EMAIL_REPLY_ID);

          $mailer->initFromTemplate('Auto Ticket First Response Template');

          // Update the email subject
          $mailer->Subject = sprintf("%s [ Ticket Id : %s ] Re : %s",
            $focus->column_fields['ticket_no'],
            $focus->id,
            $focus->column_fields['ticket_title']
          );

          $mailer->SendTo( $sendToEmail, '', false, false, true );
        }
      }        
    }
  }
}

?>
```

**Step 6: Create email template named as "Auto Ticket First Response"**

This is an acknowledgement email Company Support automatically sends after client sends email to support.company@gmail.com

To create Email Template go to Settings/E-Mail Templates; Select New Template and name it as "Auto Ticket First Response"

**Step 7: Create a new PHP file and name it as RegisterHelpDeskHandler.php**

Place the following code & execute the file

```
<?php
/*+**********************************************************************************
 * The contents of this file are subject to the vtiger CRM Public License Version 1.0
 * ("License"); You may not use this file except in compliance with the License
 * The Original Code is:  vtiger CRM Open Source
 * The Initial Developer of the Original Code is vtiger.
 * Portions created by vtiger are Copyright (C) vtiger.
 * All Rights Reserved.
 ************************************************************************************/

$Vtiger_Utils_Log = true;

include_once 'vtlib/Vtiger/Module.php';
include_once 'vtlib/Vtiger/Event.php';

$moduleInstance = Vtiger_Module::getInstance('HelpDesk');
Vtiger_Event::register($moduleInstance, 'vtiger.entity.aftersave', 'HelpDeskHandler', 'modules/HelpDesk/HelpDeskHandler.php');
?>
```

To execute, simply type the following URL

```
http://localhost:8888/registerHelpDeskHandler.php
```

You should see the following output in the browser

```
Registering Event vtiger.entity.aftersave with [modules/HelpDesk/HelpDeskHandler.php] HelpDeskHandler ... DONE
```

**Step 9: Check for the bug!**

*If you are on VTiger 5.2.0,* the bug is already fixed!

**If not**, go to modules/Settings/MailScanner/core/MailScannerAction.php and replace the entire code with the following code

```
<?php
/*********************************************************************************
 ** The contents of this file are subject to the vtiger CRM Public License Version 1.0
 * ("License"); You may not use this file except in compliance with the License
 * The Original Code is:  vtiger CRM Open Source
 * The Initial Developer of the Original Code is vtiger.
 * Portions created by vtiger are Copyright (C) vtiger.
 * All Rights Reserved.
 *
 ********************************************************************************/

require_once('modules/Emails/Emails.php');
require_once('modules/HelpDesk/HelpDesk.php');
require_once('modules/Users/Users.php');
require_once('modules/Documents/Documents.php');

/**
 * Mail Scanner Action
 */
class Vtiger_MailScannerAction {
    // actionid for this instance
    var $actionid  = false; 
    // scanner to which this action is associated
    var $scannerid = false;
    // type of mailscanner action
    var $actiontype= false;
    // text representation of action
    var $actiontext= false;
    // target module for action
    var $module    = false;
    // lookup information while taking action
    var $lookup    = false;

    // Storage folder to use
    var $STORAGE_FOLDER = 'storage/mailscanner/';

    /** DEBUG functionality */
    var $debug     = false;
    function log($message) {
        global $log;
        if($log && $this->debug) { $log->debug($message); }
        else if($this->debug) echo "$message\n";
    }

    /**
     * Constructor.
     */
    function __construct($foractionid) {
        $this->initialize($foractionid);        
    }

    /**
     * Initialize this instance.
     */
    function initialize($foractionid) {
        global $adb;
        $result = $adb->pquery("SELECT * FROM vtiger_mailscanner_actions WHERE actionid=? ORDER BY sequence", Array($foractionid));

        if($adb->num_rows($result)) {
            $this->actionid   = $adb->query_result($result, 0, 'actionid');
            $this->scannerid  = $adb->query_result($result, 0, 'scannerid');
            $this->actiontype = $adb->query_result($result, 0, 'actiontype');
            $this->module     = $adb->query_result($result, 0, 'module');
            $this->lookup     = $adb->query_result($result, 0, 'lookup');
            $this->actiontext = "$this->actiontype,$this->module,$this->lookup";
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create/Update the information of Action into database.
     */
    function update($ruleid, $actiontext) {
        global $adb;

        $inputparts = explode(',', $actiontext);
        $this->actiontype = $inputparts[0]; // LINK, CREATE
        $this->module     = $inputparts[1]; // Module name
        $this->lookup     = $inputparts[2]; // FROM, TO

        $this->actiontext = $actiontext;

        if($this->actionid) {
            $adb->pquery("UPDATE vtiger_mailscanner_actions SET scannerid=?, actiontype=?, module=?, lookup=? WHERE actionid=?",
                Array($this->scannerid, $this->actiontype, $this->module, $this->lookup, $this->actionid));
        } else {
            $this->sequence = $this->__nextsequence();
            $adb->pquery("INSERT INTO vtiger_mailscanner_actions(scannerid, actiontype, module, lookup, sequence) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)",
                Array($this->scannerid, $this->actiontype, $this->module, $this->lookup, $this->sequence));
            $this->actionid = $adb->database->Insert_ID();
        }
        $checkmapping = $adb->pquery("SELECT COUNT(*) AS ruleaction_count FROM vtiger_mailscanner_ruleactions 
            WHERE ruleid=? AND actionid=?", Array($ruleid, $this->actionid));
        if($adb->num_rows($checkmapping) && !$adb->query_result($checkmapping, 0, 'ruleaction_count')) {
            $adb->pquery("INSERT INTO vtiger_mailscanner_ruleactions(ruleid, actionid) VALUES(?,?)", 
                Array($ruleid, $this->actionid));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Delete the actions from tables.
     */
    function delete() {
        global $adb;
        if($this->actionid) {
            $adb->pquery("DELETE FROM vtiger_mailscanner_actions WHERE actionid=?", Array($this->actionid));
            $adb->pquery("DELETE FROM vtiger_mailscanner_ruleactions WHERE actionid=?", Array($this->actionid));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get next sequence of Action to use.
     */
    function __nextsequence() {
        global $adb;
        $seqres = $adb->pquery("SELECT max(sequence) AS max_sequence FROM vtiger_mailscanner_actions", Array());
        $maxsequence = 0;
        if($adb->num_rows($seqres)) {
            $maxsequence = $adb->query_result($seqres, 0, 'max_sequence');
        }
        ++$maxsequence;
        return $maxsequence;
    }

    /**
     * Apply the action on the mail record.
     */
    function apply($mailscanner, $mailrecord, $mailscannerrule, $matchresult) {
        $returnid = false;
        if($this->actiontype == 'CREATE') {
            if($this->module == 'HelpDesk') {
                $returnid = $this->__CreateTicket($mailscanner, $mailrecord); 
            }
        } else if($this->actiontype == 'LINK') {
            $returnid = $this->__LinkToRecord($mailscanner, $mailrecord);
        } else if($this->actiontype == 'UPDATE') {
            if($this->module == 'HelpDesk') {
                $returnid = $this->__UpdateTicket($mailscanner, $mailrecord, 
                    $mailscannerrule->hasRegexMatch($matchresult));
            }
        }
        return $returnid;
    }

    /**
     * Update ticket action.
     */
    function __UpdateTicket($mailscanner, $mailrecord, $regexMatchInfo) {
        global $adb;
        $returnid = false;

        $usesubject = false;
        if($this->lookup == 'SUBJECT') {
            // If regex match was performed on subject use the matched group
            // to lookup the ticket record
            if($regexMatchInfo) $usesubject = $regexMatchInfo['matches'];
            else $usesubject = $mailrecord->_subject;

            // Get the ticket record that was created by SENDER earlier
            $fromemail = $mailrecord->_from[0];

            $linkfocus = $mailscanner->GetTicketRecord($usesubject, $fromemail);
            $relatedid = $linkfocus->column_fields[parent_id];

            // If matching ticket is found, update comment, attach email
            if($linkfocus) {
                $timestamp = $adb->formatDate(date('YmdHis'), true);
                $adb->pquery("INSERT INTO vtiger_ticketcomments(ticketid, comments, ownerid, ownertype, createdtime) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)",
                    Array($linkfocus->id, $mailrecord->getBodyText(), $relatedid, 'customer', $timestamp));
                // Set the ticket status to Open if its Closed
                $adb->pquery("UPDATE vtiger_troubletickets set status=? WHERE ticketid=? AND status='Closed'", Array('Open', $linkfocus->id));

                $returnid = $this->__CreateNewEmail($mailrecord, $this->module, $linkfocus);

            } else {
                // TODO If matching ticket was not found, create ticket?
                // $returnid = $this->__CreateTicket($mailscanner, $mailrecord);
            }
        }
        return $returnid;
    }

    /**
     * Create ticket action.
     */
    function __CreateTicket($mailscanner, $mailrecord) {
        // Prepare data to create trouble ticket
        $usetitle = $mailrecord->_subject;
        $description = $mailrecord->getBodyText();

        // There will be only on FROM address to email, so pick the first one
        $fromemail = $mailrecord->_from[0]; 
        $linktoid = $mailscanner->LookupContact($fromemail);
        if(!$linktoid) $linktoid = $mailscanner->LookupAccount($fromemail);

        /** Now Create Ticket **/
        global $current_user;
        if(!$current_user) $current_user = new Users();
        $current_user->id = 1;

        // Create trouble ticket record
        $ticket = new HelpDesk();
        $ticket->column_fields['ticket_title'] = $usetitle;
        $ticket->column_fields['description'] = $description;
        $ticket->column_fields['ticketstatus'] = 'Open';
        $ticket->column_fields['assigned_user_id'] = $current_user->id;
        if($linktoid) $ticket->column_fields['parent_id'] = $linktoid;
        $ticket->save('HelpDesk');

        // Associate any attachement of the email to ticket
        $this->__SaveAttachements($mailrecord, 'HelpDesk', $ticket);

        return $ticket->id;
    }

    /**
     * Add email to CRM record like Contacts/Accounts
     */
    function __LinkToRecord($mailscanner, $mailrecord) {
        $linkfocus = false;

        $useemail  = false;
        if($this->lookup == 'FROM') $useemail = $mailrecord->_from;
        else if($this->lookup == 'TO') $useemail = $mailrecord->_to;

        if($this->module == 'Contacts') {
            foreach($useemail as $email) {
                $linkfocus = $mailscanner->GetContactRecord($email);
                if($linkfocus) break;
            }
        } else if($this->module == 'Accounts') {
            foreach($useemail as $email) {          
                $linkfocus = $mailscanner->GetAccountRecord($email);
                if($linkfocus) break;
            }
        }

        $returnid = false;
        if($linkfocus) {
            $returnid = $this->__CreateNewEmail($mailrecord, $this->module, $linkfocus);
        }
        return $returnid;
    }

    /**
     * Create new Email record (and link to given record) including attachements
     */
    function __CreateNewEmail($mailrecord, $module, $linkfocus) {   
        global $current_user, $adb;
        if(!$current_user) $current_user = new Users();
        $current_user->id = 1;

        $focus = new Emails();
        $focus->column_fields['parent_type'] = $module;
        $focus->column_fields['activitytype'] = 'Emails';
        $focus->column_fields['parent_id'] = "$linkfocus->id@-1|";
        $focus->column_fields['subject'] = $mailrecord->_subject;

        $focus->column_fields['description'] = $mailrecord->getBodyHTML();
        $focus->column_fields['assigned_user_id'] = $linkfocus->column_fields['assigned_user_id'];
        $focus->column_fields["date_start"]= date('Y-m-d', $mailrecord->_date);

        $from=$mailrecord->_from[0];
        $to = $mailrecord->_to[0];
        $cc = (!empty($mailrecord->_cc))? implode(',', $mailrecord->_cc) : '';
        $bcc= (!empty($mailrecord->_bcc))? implode(',', $mailrecord->_bcc) : '';
        $flag=''; // 'SENT'/'SAVED'
        //emails field were restructured and to,bcc and cc field are JSON arrays
        $focus->column_fields['from_email'] = $from;
        $focus->column_fields['saved_toid'] = $to;
        $focus->column_fields['ccmail'] = $cc;
        $focus->column_fields['bccmail'] = $bcc;  
        $focus->save('Emails');

        $emailid = $focus->id;

        $this->log("Created [$focus->id]: $mailrecord->_subject linked it to " . $linkfocus->id);

        // TODO: Handle attachments of the mail (inline/file)
        $this->__SaveAttachements($mailrecord, 'Emails', $focus);

        return $emailid;
    }

    /**
     * Save attachments from the email and add it to the module record.
     */
    function __SaveAttachements($mailrecord, $basemodule, $basefocus) {
        global $adb;

        // If there is no attachments return
        if(!$mailrecord->_attachments) return;

        $userid = $basefocus->column_fields['assigned_user_id'];
        $setype = "$basemodule Attachment";

        $date_var = $adb->formatDate(date('YmdHis'), true);

        foreach($mailrecord->_attachments as $filename=>$filecontent) {
            $attachid = $adb->getUniqueId('vtiger_crmentity');
            $description = $filename;
            $usetime = $adb->formatDate($date_var, true);

            $adb->pquery("INSERT INTO vtiger_crmentity(crmid, smcreatorid, smownerid, 
                modifiedby, setype, description, createdtime, modifiedtime, presence, deleted)
                VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", 
                Array($attachid, $userid, $userid, $userid, $setype, $description, $usetime, $usetime, 1, 0));

            $issaved = $this->__SaveAttachmentFile($attachid, $filename, $filecontent);
            if($issaved) {
                // Create document record
                $document = new Documents();
                $document->column_fields['notes_title']      = $filename;
                $document->column_fields['filename']         = $filename;
                $document->column_fields['filestatus']       = 1;
                $document->column_fields['filelocationtype'] = 'I';
                $document->column_fields['folderid']         = 1; // Default Folder 
                $document->column_fields['assigned_user_id'] = $userid;
                $document->save('Documents');

                // Link file attached to document
                $adb->pquery("INSERT INTO vtiger_seattachmentsrel(crmid, attachmentsid) VALUES(?,?)", 
                    Array($document->id, $attachid));

                // Link document to base record
                $adb->pquery("INSERT INTO vtiger_senotesrel(crmid, notesid) VALUES(?,?)", 
                    Array($basefocus->id, $document->id));              
            }
        }   
    }

    /**
     * Save the attachment to the file
     */
    function __SaveAttachmentFile($attachid, $filename, $filecontent) {
        global $adb;

        $dirname = $this->STORAGE_FOLDER;
        if(!is_dir($dirname)) mkdir($dirname);

        $description = $filename;
        $filename = str_replace(' ', '-', $filename);
        $saveasfile = "$dirname$attachid" . "_$filename";
        if(!file_exists($saveasfile)) {

            $this->log("Saved attachement as $saveasfile\n");

            $fh = fopen($saveasfile, 'wb');
            fwrite($fh, $filecontent);
            fclose($fh);
        }

        $mimetype = MailAttachmentMIME::detect($saveasfile);

        $adb->pquery("INSERT INTO vtiger_attachments SET attachmentsid=?, name=?, description=?, type=?, path=?",
            Array($attachid, $filename, $description, $mimetype, $dirname));

        return true;
    }
}
?>
```

**Step10: If you still face problems, and still cant get the update ticket functionality;
 Check out the VTiger Forums.**

[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZU7Q.jpg*emphasized text**emphasized text*

Comment: on v.7.x regex should be   .?Ticket Id : ([0-9]+).?